# Data context in Meteor rendered callback unreliable

Tags: javascript, meteor

I've had this issue for a while, but since it's on the admin side of my app, I just dealt with it. Now it's just annoying.

Route is `post_detail`. I specified a data context for that route with something like this:

```
data: function() {
    return Posts.findOne(this.params._id);
}
```

So the route should have a data context. Subscriptions are in a `waitOn` function.

In the rendered callback for that route, I have this:

```
var tag_obj = this.data.tags;
```

Most of the time, this.data is `undefined`. Usually (but not always), when I refresh the page, I get the data. Sometimes I have to try a couple of times, other times I have to go back and forth between pages to get the data to show up. It's unpredictable.

It seems like the data context just isn't always ready by the time the rendered callback is called...but I thought that was the point of `waitOn` and the `rendered` callback? I've tried using `document.ready()` and a `delay` function to give it time to load but haven't had any luck.

Any idea what could be causing this?

Is there any way to wait for a data context to be ready within the `rendered` callback? All the examples I've seen just assume it's already there and ready to go...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find it a bit weird too, but Iron Router doesn't wait for all the subscriptions to be ready by default. But if you somewhere add `Router.onBeforeAction('loading')`, it will wait for all the subscriptions to be ready before rendering the template.

Comment: Thanks...odd to have to do that, but it worked like a charm!!